# What are the advantages of using SendGrid Web API instead of SMTP as the transport mechanism for sending emails in Django?

Tags: python, django, email, sendgrid

In the [Django Docs for SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/django.html), it says:

> You may also send emails with Django by using the django-sendgrid-v5 library, which utilizes the Web API instead of SMTP as the transport mechanism.

The use-case for my emails are simply verifying emails when users sign up for an account.

Answer (score 3):

There might be situations in which the SMTP protocol cannot be used by your application: for example, it might be behind a firewall or gateway that only allows outgoing HTTP/HTTPS connections. The web API would also work through a proxy. It also looks like with the HTTP API, an API key is used for authentication, and you won't have to provide your SendGrid username and password to your application.

If you also import the SendGrid Python library into your project, you would also be able to utilise all the services that SendGrid offers, as opposed to just sending emails.

If all you need to do is send emails and your application can reach the SendGrid server over SMTP, however, both methods should work fine.